# Two differents views depending on the URL file extension using Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to have the same request mapping but resolve to different view depending on the file extension. I have two JSPs one that renders HTML and another that renders XML. Depending on the file extension I should resolve to the corresponding jsp.

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class FileManagementController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/filemanagements", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list() {
        //if file extension .xml return  /filemanagement/listXml
        //if no file extension present return /filemanagement/list
    }

}
```

And I Have the following y Root of my WebApp:

/jsp/filemanagement/list.jsp

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
```

..

/jsp/filemanagement/listXml.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@page contentType="text/xml" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

....

This is how I have configured my ViewResolver in the servletContext.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Did you try just another method with a different request mapping?

Comment: A simple way to do it would be to include PathVariable indicating what type of view to return:  `@RequestMapping("/foo/{viewtype}/myrequest.do")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`.  From the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html):

> This view resolver uses the requested media type to select a suitable View for a request.
>
> If the requested path has a file extension and if the `setFavorPathExtension(boolean)` property is true, the mediaTypes property is inspected for a matching media type.

There is also a [section of the ref manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations) covering this resolver.

Comment: But how the controller will return a different view according to the file extension. For example if a request to /filemanagement/list.xml is made /filemanagement/listXml.jsp should be returned so InternalResourceViewResolver will render that view.

Comment: @Alfredo: The controllers are supposed to return symbolic view names, not filenames. For example, return "list" rather than "listXml.jsp". The view resolver then maps that name to a view. The doc links I posted describe how to do it.

Comment: My bad. I meant /filemanagement/listXml without the jsp suffix. UrlBasedViewResolver that's what they do. Map that logical view to a physical url using prefix and sufix attribute. If I return "list" how does the resolver is going to know that "list" means listXml.jsp in some case and list.jsp in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Following skaffman advice. I did solve this using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.

**servletContext.xml:**

```
<bean id="resourceResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

The resolvers are picked up automatically by ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/filemanagements")
public class FileManagementController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list(@RequestParam(required=false) String contentType) {
        return new ModelAndView(baseLogicView + "/list");
    }

    private static final String baseLogicView = "/filemanagement";
}
```

**These jsps:**

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/filemanagements/list.jsp
/WEB-INF/jsp/filemanagements/listXml.jsp
```

**Resource bundle views.properties:**

```
/filemanagement/list.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
/filemanagement/list.url=/WEB-INF/jsp/filemanagement/listXml.jsp
/filemanagement/list.contentType=text/xml
```

It was necessary to specify the contentType there because if you don't it defaults to this **"text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"** even if you set <%@ page contentType="text/xml" %> in the JSP that renders the XML.

After that I could do the following requests:

```
http://localhost:8080/filemanagement-web/filemanagements (list.jsp)
http://localhost:8080/filemanagement-web/filemanagements.html (list.jsp)
http://localhost:8080/filemanagement-web/filemanagements.xml (listXml.jsp)
```

Comment: not a single line of your solution shows ContentNegotiatingViewResolver. You're using InternalResourceViewResolver and ResourceBundeViewResolver, thats it. Misleading title.